# Psycopg2 connect() TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

---

Hi I'm trying to connect to my database as always. I used to do that and everything worked fine, I've also created that database
If I'm doing the same in python Terminal - everything is working - I can easily connect to my database and execute my sql queries. My code:

```
from psycopg2 import connect

def create_connection():
    cnx = connect(
    user="postgres",
    password="*******",
    host="localhost",
    dbname="exercises_db")

    cnx.autocommit = True 
    cursor = cnx.cursor() 

    return (cnx, cursor)

def close_connection(cnx, cursor):
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()


def create_tables():
    cnx, cursor = connect()   

    customers = '''
    CREATE TABLE customers (
     customer_id serial,
     name varchar(255), 
     surname varchar(255),
     PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
    );
    '''
    cursor.execute(customers)

   orders = '''
    CREATE TABLE orders (
     order_id serial,
     customer_id  int REFERENCES customers(customer_id), 
     description text,
     PRIMARY KEY(order_id)
     FOREIGN KEY(customer_id)

    );
     '''

     cursor.execute(orders)

     products = '''
       CREATE TABLE products (
        product_id serial,
        name varchar(255),
        price decimal(5, 2)
        PRIMARY_KEY(product_id)
       );
        '''

    cursor.execute(products)

    close_connection(cnx, cursor)


 create_tables()
```

And the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "A1_1.py", line 65, in <module>
 create_tables()
 File "A1_1.py", line 26, in create_tables
 cnx, cursor = connect()   
 File "A1_1.py", line 20, in connect
 cnx = connect( host="localhost", database="exercises_db")
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'
```

Comment: Mikey, are you saying that this code used to work and then stopped? What did you change? If that's not the case, what IS different?

Comment: Connect doesn't have host keyword. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html?highlight=connect#psycopg2.connect

Comment: Actually I finally found the problem - I'm refferencing to connect() function which doesn't exist I shoult write: cnx, cursor = create_connection()

Answer (score 1):

Actually I finally found the problem - I'm refferencing to connect() function which doesn't exist I shoult write: 
`cnx, cursor = create_connection()`
I also found later some other mistakes like PRIMARY_KEY instead of PRIMARY KEY. Now I finally succesfully added the databases. Sorry for wasting your time guys :)